# Problem with React js with DataGrid Selected Rows

Tags: reactjs, datagridview

I have a problem with this code. Someone can help me?
I will explain my problem. I want to display the select rows from the data grid 'Available' in another data grid called 'Selected'.

```
const Home = () => {
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);
  const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      " ENDPOINT "
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        if (Array.isArray(json.results)) {
          const dataID = json.results.map((row, index) => ({
            id: index + 1,
            Model: row.Model,
            "Serial Number": row["Serial Number"],
            Date_start: new Date(row.Date_start).toLocaleDateString(),
          }));
          setTableData(dataID);
        }
      });
  }, []);

  const handleCheckboxSelect = (selectedItems) => {
    const selectedRowData = selectedItems.map((item) => item.row);
    setSelectedRows(selectedRowData);
  };

  const columns = [
    {
      field: "Serial Number",
      headerName: "Serial Number",
      flex: 1,
      width: 300,
    },
    {
      field: "Model",
      headerName: "Model",
      flex: 1,
      width: 300,
    },
    {
      field: "Date_start",
      headerName: "Break-in Date",
      flex: 1,
      width: 300,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <Box>
      <Header />
      <h1 style={{ marginLeft: "25px", marginBottom: "20px" }}>
        Available
      </h1>

      <DataGrid
        checkboxSelection
        disableColumnFilter
        disableColumnSelector
        disableDensitySelector
        rows={tableData}
        columns={columns}
        onRowModelChange={handleCheckboxSelect}
        initialState={{
          pagination: {
            paginationModel: { pageSize: 5, page: 0 },
          },
        }}
      />

      <div>
        <h3>Selected</h3>
        {selectedRows.length === 0 ? (
          <p>No rows selected.</p>
        ) : (
          <ul>
            {selectedRows.map((row, index) => (
              <li key={index + 1}>{`${row["Serial Number"]} - ${row.Model} - ${row.Date_start}`}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

In the following code I was trying to display them in a "clear" way without the component data grid as you can see in the code.
Thanks to everyone who can help me.